# Pollard’s rho method: use the polynomial $f(x) = x^2$, show for $j<i$, $a_i ≡a_j \pmod p ⇔ 2^{i−1} ≡2^{j−1} \pmod k$, $p$ is a prime factor of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n > 1$ be a number which we wish to factorize. Suppose we
try to change the implementation of Pollard’s rho method to use the polynomial $f(x) = x^2$ instead. That is,
we define our sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ by choosing $a_1 ∈\{0,1,\ldots ,n −1\}$
at random and then defining $a_i$ to be the remainder of $a_{i−1}^2 \pmod n$, for all $i ≥2$. Assume that our chosen $a_1$ is coprime to $n$.

Let $p$ denote a prime factor of $n$, and let $k$ be the
multiplicative order of $a_1 \pmod p$. Show that for $j < i$,
$a_i ≡a_j \pmod p ⇔ 2^{i−1} ≡2^{j−1} \pmod k$.

I have checked other questions in [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4160211/why-use-a-polynomial-to-generate-random-numbers-for-pollards-rho-factorization).

### Attempt

From $a_i \equiv a_j \pmod p$:

$$a_i - a_j \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

$$a_i - a_j = bp \quad \text{for some integer b}$$

Since $a_i$ and $a_j$ are obtained from the polynomial $f(x) = x^2$ modulo $n$:

$$a_i = a_{i-1}^2 \pmod n$$
$$a_j = a_{j-1}^2 \pmod n$$

Then we get:

$$a_{i-1}^2 - a_{j-1}^2 \pmod n = bp$$

This implies:

$$(a_{i-1} + a_{j-1})(a_{i-1} - a_{j-1}) \pmod n = bp$$

$$a_i - a_j \equiv 0 \pmod p \quad \Rightarrow \quad a_{i-1} - a_{j-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

---

From $2^{i-1} \equiv 2^{j-1} \pmod k$:

$$2^{i-1} - 2^{j-1} = mk \quad \text{for some integer }m.$$

Now, we can use the fact that $2^{i-1} - 2^{j-1}$ is also a power of 2:

$$2^{i-1} - 2^{j-1} = 2^{j-1}(2^{i-j} - 1) = mk$$

This implies:

$$2^{i-j} - 1 = \frac{mk}{2^{j-1}}$$

Since the left-hand side is an integer, the right-hand side must also be an integer.

Comment: A trivial induction shows $\,a_k \equiv {a_1}^{2^{\large k-1}}\!\pmod{\!n}\,$ [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) also $\!\bmod p,\,$ by $\,p\mid n,\,$ thus 
$$\left[\bmod p\!:\,\ a_i\equiv a_j \iff {a_1}^{2^{\large i-1}}\! \equiv {a_1}^{2^{\large j-1}}\right]\!\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{MOR}\!\!}\iff 2^{i-1}\equiv 2^{j-1}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!{\rm ord}_p(a_1)}\qquad\qquad$$
by $\rm\color{#c00}{MOR}$ = [Mod Order reduction Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how to continue your approach to solve the problem. Instead, from

$$a_i \equiv a_{i-1}^2 \pmod{n}, \;\; i \ge 2$$

we get $a_2 \equiv a_1^2 \pmod{n}$, $a_3 \equiv a_2^2 \equiv (a_1^2)^2 \equiv a_1^{2^2} \pmod{n}$, $a_4 \equiv a_3^2 \equiv (a_1^{2^2})^2 \equiv a_1^{2^3} \pmod{n}$, and so on. We can prove, such as by induction, that for all integers $m \ge 1$,

$$a_m \equiv a_1^{2^{m - 1}} \pmod{n}$$

Since $p \mid n$, we also have $a_m \equiv a_1^{2^{m - 1}} \pmod{p}$. Thus,

$$a_i \equiv a_j \pmod{p} \iff a_1^{2^{i - 1}} \equiv a_1^{2^{j - 1}} \pmod{p} \iff 
2^{i - 1} \equiv 2^{j - 1} \pmod{k}$$

To show the last part, have $2^{i - 1} = ak + b, \; 0 \le b \lt k$ and $2^{j - 1} = ck + d, \; 0 \le d \lt k$. Also, WLOG, have $b \ge d$. We then get from the middle part above that

$$a^{ak+b} \equiv a^{ck+d} \pmod{p} \to a^b \equiv a^d \pmod{p} \to a^{b-d} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

However, $0 \le b - d \lt k$ so, since $k$ is the smallest positive integer where $a_1^k \equiv 1\pmod{p}$, this means $b - d = 0 \;\to\; b = d$, i.e., $2^{i - 1} \equiv 2^{j - 1} \pmod{k}$.

Comment: Why $a_1^{2^{i - 1}} \equiv a_1^{2^{j - 1}} \pmod{p} \iff 
2^{i - 1} \equiv 2^{j - 1} \pmod{k}$?

Comment: @Mzq The rest of the answer explains it, actually just the $\implies$ part, but the $\impliedby$ part can also be quite easily derived. Note there are other posts on this site that explain this, with at least some providing more detail and/or using different methods. Nonetheless, please look at what I wrote again and let me know if there's anything specific you don't understand.

Comment: *Please* strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: The part $p \mid n, a_m \equiv a_1^{2^{m - 1}} \pmod{n} \to a_m \equiv a_1^{2^{m - 1}} \pmod{p}$, what if $a_1^{2^{m - 1}}$ > p? why is this alway true

Comment: @Mzq In general, $a \equiv b \pmod{c} \iff c \mid a - b$. If $p \mid c$, then $c \mid a - b \;\to\; p \mid a - b$. Thus, $a \equiv b \pmod{c} \;\to\; a \equiv b \pmod{p}$. Note this has nothing to do with the sizes of $a$ or $b$ relative to $p$, including if either one is $\gt p$.